# Analytics custom UserType only shows a few users

Tags: typescript, google-analytics

We are trying to set up tracking by differentiating for different User Types: Truck Driver and Super Users. It seems to work somehow, but only for a few users (around 9) types are being set, whereas we expect many more (at least 50-80). What are we missing?

- Hypothesis 1: Only new users will have their user type set. Not existing users.
- Hypothesis 2: Some sort of throttling is going on. But we seem too small for that.
- Hypothesis 3 (rejected): You need to log out and back in (we tested this, but doesnt seem to work).

Analytics service

```
import { inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Analytics, setUserProperties } from '@angular/fire/analytics';
import { CustomParams } from '@firebase/analytics';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AnalyticsService {
  readonly #analytics = inject(Analytics);

  setUserProperties(properties: CustomParams) {
    setUserProperties(this.#analytics, properties, { global: true });
  }
}
```

Getting the UserDetails

```
#getUserDetails() {
  return this.#gateway.query('GetUser').pipe(
    tap((userDetails) => {
      if (userDetails.betaUser) {
====>   this.#analytics.setUserProperties({ user_type: userDetails.superUser ? 'superUser' : 'truckDriver' });   <=====
      }
    }),
    tap((userDetails) => this.#userDetails$.next(userDetails)),
    catchError((cause: unknown) => {
      if (cause instanceof HttpErrorResponse && cause.status === StatusCodes.UNAUTHORIZED) {
        this.#handleUnauthorizedError();
      } else {
        this.#handleUnknownError();
      }
      throw new Error('Error while retrieving user details', { cause });
    }),
  );
}
```